# ANCOVA plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following code plots the result of an ANCOVA:

```
library(HH)
ancova(weight ~ gesttime + dose, data=litter)
```

[image]

If I try to make same plot in ggplot, the slopes of the lines of best fit are not homogenous at different levels of the `dose`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(litter, aes(gesttime, weight)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ dose) + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

How can I make the same plot as outputted by `ancova()`, but using ggplot?

Comment: Hi @luciano, how do you calculate if your regression weight ~ gesttime it's different for different factor?
I mean, how do you demonstrate that this correlation is statistically different for factor "dose = 0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ggplot you need to plot the predicted values from your models using geom_line() as follows to produce what you want.

Get your model fit:

```
data(litter)
mod <- ancova(weight ~ gesttime + dose, data=litter)
pred <- predict(mod)
```

Plot it:

```
ggplot(data = cbind(litter, pred),
    aes(gesttime, weight, color=dose)) + geom_point() +
    facet_grid(. ~ dose) + geom_line(aes(y=pred))
```